# Which salary document do I provide to potential employer?

Tags: salary, job-offer, india

I have 2 years of work experience with company A. I left the job recently. After some interviews I narrowed down my choices to company B and C. I got offered a job from company B but I want to join company C.

Company C are asking for a latest salary document from me, so should I show company A CTC (Cost to Company) letter or company B CTC letter? Remember I haven't worked at company B yet, I've just got an offer which is higher than company A. I am also facing problems to get the salary slip from company A.

Comment: From a quick trip to google this seems to be an Indian thing: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/17159

Comment: Curiosity, is your employee contract is confidential? I am surprised that every new employees have to share their salaries, aren't confidential?

Answer (score 8):

> now company C is asking for a latest salary document from me so should
>   I show company A ctc letter or company B ctc letter? remember i
>   haven't work in company B yet just got offer which is higher than
>   company A.as well as i am facing problems to get company A salary
>   slip.

Since you have never actually worked for company B, then clearly your "latest salary document" needs to come from company A.

Answer (score 2):

Your latest salary document is the one from **Company A.**

**However,** that doesn't mean you can't let them know you are considering another offer, and use it to negotiate.